# Understanding multithreading C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to understand multithreading. I have an example that runs two threads from Main method in console app.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First :" + x); 
    }
}).Start();

new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second :" + x);
    }
}).Start();

Console.ReadKey();
```

What's happening is, My console is coming black, nothing written on it, but when I press any key then it displays proper results. Why?

Comment: Remove the final ReadKey

Comment: Because `IO` operations to `Console` are synchronized. `ReadKey()` places a block on the `IO`.

Comment: ReadKey() waits for a keystroke

Comment: I think important to remember is that you didn't create a 2 thread sample but a 3 thread sample. (main thread is also a thread) That's why your readkey can happen before the print of data.

Comment: @GrantWinney Are you testing it in LinqPad by any chance?

Comment: @GrantWinney Is that with a breakpoint on the `Console.ReadKey()`? I'm getting about half (limit of 10) printed before it hits the breakpoint. Apparently I was wrong, `Console.ReadKey()` does not always put a block on the IO stream - I'm definitely getting values printed after `Console.ReadKey()` executes (without any key press).

Comment: @GrantWinney I don't see it either (I get the same result as you). I'm a bit surprised `ReadKey()` isn't blocking the IO, I would have expected the result OP is getting.

Comment: Your experiment should teach you two fundamental rules of writing multithreaded programming. First, **never write multithreaded programs where two threads try to manipulate a user interface**.  Such programs are almost always broken and wrong. Dedicate a single thread to communicating with the user; other threads must convince that thread to do the work.  Second, **learn to expect that the world does not work normally anymore**. In single threaded programming you have guarantees about the order in which things happen in time built in to the language. Those guarantees go away.

Comment: @EricLippert Do you have any insight into why a `Console.ReadKey()` would block the IO in some cases, and *not* block it in other cases?

Comment: @Rob: Read my two fundamental rules again: (1) programs that try to do UI on two threads are broken, and (2) don't expect anything to behave normally. I have no expectation that the broken program given will produce *any* behaviour whatsoever. Moreover, I don't expect that the behaviour of a broken program will be consistent across multiple runs or across machines. **I also don't expect that the behaviour will be inconsistent**. Broken programs are broken; they are not required to be consistent or inconsistent in their bad behaviour.

Comment: @EricLippert can you please put some light on what your second point mean? As much I can think it should not block for IO rather complete remaining task. And wondering how it is executing other thread after IO?

Comment: @Imad: My second point means that what you think a program *should* do no longer applies when you start writing multithreaded programs. In single-threaded programs you can say "these variables are going to stay the same until something changes them".  In multithreaded programs you must always reason "these variables are constantly changing until something keeps them still". That is a fundamentally different attitude, and it means that your intuitions about what "should" happen can be very different from reality.

Comment: @EricLippert Thats OK. But at least it show give guarantee that all threads will be executing, may be in different order.

Comment: @Imad: I have results same as Rob and Grant Winney. I think this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fc2bc85-a079-428e-8c48-c281ff47a6ec/consolereadkey-behaves-differently-on-different-environment?forum=netfxbcl is somewhat related. Although I can't find `lock` in Console.ReadKey code.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Actually I am saying something even weaker than that. I'm saying that prior to the empirical evidence we've gathered in this comment thread, which indicates that the behaviour is inconsistent across machines, **I would not have cared to predict whether the behaviour would be consistent or inconsistent**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of us (looking at the comments under the question) see the new threads execute in entirety before `Console.ReadKey()` is called, while others see the initial thread preempt the new ones, waiting for input via `Console.ReadKey()` *before* executing the new threads.

You've got three threads all doing their own thing, all potentially writing to the console and performing other logic, and you're not really in control of which one executes at any particular moment.

From what [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) said, this behavior is expected, and the way you're executing the new threads is predictably unpredictable. *(reposted his comment here in case the comments are cleaned up)*

> Read my two fundamental rules again: (1) programs that try to do UI on two threads are broken, and (2) don't expect anything to behave normally. I have no expectation that the broken program given will produce any behaviour whatsoever. Moreover, I don't expect that the behaviour of a broken program will be consistent across multiple runs or across machines. **I also don't expect that the behaviour will be inconsistent.** Broken programs are broken; they are not required to be consistent or inconsistent in their bad behaviour.

There is a call that will allow you to block the initial (main) thread (which happens to be the calling thread), until the new threads are finished executing, and that's [Thread.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You're still not in control of which order the two new threads execute and write to the console, but at least the initial thread is paused.

```
var threads = new Thread[] {
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First :" + x);
        }
    }),
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second :" + x);
        }
    })
};

// start the threads
foreach (var t in threads)
    t.Start();

// block the initial thread until the new threads are finished
foreach (var t in threads)
    t.Join();

// Now the following line won't execute until both threads are done
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This answer illustrates a key point: when you live in the multithreaded world where everything is moving that is not forced to stay still, there are only a small number of guarantees about what happens in what order. As it happens, starting and joining threads *do* give you some guarantees: effects that logically happen before starts really do happen before starts, and joins will not return until the work of the thread can be observed to be done. Now: what I just said is an oversimplification of the real situation. The C# specification gives the details.

Comment: +1 for Join but I was assuming that if any thread is waiting for some resource (like Console.ReadKey waits for keyboard input.) and it's not getting that then other threads will start processing. Here I am making application to wait for much time by stopping execution using debugger but still other threads (i.e. other than Main thread do not execute). That means I am not getting that asynchronous behavior that I was supposed to get. My point is if my application is waiting for keyboard input then other threads should have started their execution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me call the first spawned thread as thread1, the next spawned thread as thread2. Moreover let's call the thread which creates thread1 and thread2 as mainthread.

Loosely speaking, there is no guarantee that code in thread1 will get executed before that of thread2 or mainthread. So depending on various circumstances, it might execute some `Console.WriteLine()` before stopping for `Console.ReadKey()`.
Why does it stop for `Console.ReadKey()` you may ask; since the Console I/O is synchronized. A `lock` statement around the Console.* call might make it more obvious (for demo code)

If you want the other 2 threads to finish processing before calling `Console.ReadKey()` (blocking I/O call), you should call `thread1.Join()` and `thread2.Join()` before calling `Console.ReadKey()`

Comment: Console I/O is synchronized. That makes sense.